# How to use Eval in ternary-operator, aspx page

Tags: asp.net, eval, ternary-operator

So, I'm trying to display 2 different html codes depending on the bitColors value. I'm getting the given errors, how can it be solved only on the aspx page?

```
<%# Eval("bitColor").ToString() == "true" 
    ? "<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='color: rgb(<%# Eval("chrColorCode") %>)'></i><%# Eval("varDisplayName")%>" 
    : "<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='display: none'></i><%# Eval("varDisplayName")%>" 
%>
```

I get in `? "<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='color: rgb(<%# Eval("chrColorCode") %>)'></i><%# Eval("varDisplayName")%>"` :

> Compiler Error Message: CS1010: Newline in constant

or when hovering over the following code in vs: `Eval("chrColorCode")`

> "Syntax error, ":" expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that you need, you need not to wrap Eval again into c# code quotes once you have already opened it.

```
<%# Eval("bitColor").ToString() == "true" 
? ("<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='color: rgb(" + Eval("chrColorCode") + ")'></i>" + Eval("varDisplayName")) 
: ("<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='display: none'></i>" + Eval("varDisplayName")) %>
```

Comment: If I use this, I get : System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: Yes, what complication could that cause?

Comment: Sorry, just had time to check up. I've tried it but it dosn't display any data from the Eval()s, not even the circle from the <i> class

Comment: It is working for me, inspect it and check you will see the <i tag there. Does the source that is bind to repeater contains all those values you have used it in Eval?

Comment: One more thing, if you are using boolean for bitColor then make sure you will need to do tolower for Eval("bitColor").ToString() to Eval("bitColor").ToString().ToLower().

Comment: Got it, sorry I don't have full acces to database, diidn't notice that I might not have the bitColor available... Thank you, It works :)

Answer (score 0):

All C# code must be wrapped by <%# %>, but "returned" values are not

```
<%# Eval("bitColor").ToString() == "true"? %> "<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='color: rgb(<%# Eval("chrColorCode")%>)'></i><%# Eval("varDisplayName")%>" 
<%#:%> "<i class='fa fa-circle-o' style='display: none'></i><%# Eval("varDisplayName")%>"
```

Comment: The expression in a <%= %> or <%# %> block cannot be an empty string.